How to merge SVG masks?
I'm trying to "merge" two masks in SVG and apply them in a way that the white part of both masks is visible in the shape I apply it to.
I read that the solution might be feComposite, but I can't get it working... This is what i have so far:
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask1" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="black"/>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="white"/>
    </mask>
    <mask id="mask2" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="black"/>
      <rect x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" fill="white"/>
    </mask>
    <filter id="combinedMask">
            <feComposite in="mask1" in2="mask2" operator="over"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="red" mask="url(#combinedMask)"/>
</svg

The desired output in the case above would be this:
output

Your example code is probably simplified. However, if you don't need  any semi-transparency or  stroke related masking - you should try <clipPath> as it is usually faster than mask (introducing a rgba rendering context - especially in webkit browsers you may see quirky results like blurry rendering when zooming as webkit tends to render masked elements only once at a fixed resolution). See codepen example

You can't use an ID reference from outside the filter directly as an "in" within an SVG filter. You can only use SourceGraphic, SourceAlpha or a reference to a previous "result=" within the same filter. If you want to use an ID, you have to import it into the filter using "feImage" first - and feImage won't accept a mask AFAIK.

You can combine the two masks in a mask.


<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask1" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="white"/>
    </mask>
    <mask id="mask2" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200">
      <rect x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" fill="white"/>
    </mask>
    <mask id="combinedMask" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200">
      <rect width="200" height="200" fill="white" mask="url(#mask1)"/>
      <rect width="200" height="200" fill="white" mask="url(#mask2)"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="red" mask="url(#combinedMask)"/>
</svg>



